# Property file changes not picked after compilation in intelliJ with Jetty server

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jetty

Property file changes are not picked after compilation in IntelliJ IDEA while the java file changes are reflected without restarting the server. I am using maven with jetty server plugin

Comment: How do you run your application? What is the application type?

Comment: It Spring-Rest application. use postman to test the application

Comment: Provide demonstration code, configuration, pom.xml etc.  This question is far too vague to render any answers.